# To where will Sam not return?

Tags: death-stranding

> Deadman: (via codec) It’s a miracle either of you made it back. When someone with DOOMS hooks up to a BB, your feelings and memories cause feedback, like with a speaker. It amplifies fears and stress and runs the risk of taking you to a place from which you will not return. I’m sorry, but this BB has been pushed beyond its limits. Disposal is the only option.

Which place is this to which Sam will not return? Is he is not a repatriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on context, the "place from which you will not return" seems to be madness, the feedback loop resulting in the person being trapped in an endless cycle of fears and stress, unable to break free from it and die, which is a condition with a repatriate such as Sam can recover from.

Comment: Well then it’s a place he can return..

Comment: @GuilhermeWoolley: Except, no, what Deadman is saying is that if the feedback loop goes wrong, he can't return to sanity. Now whether Deadman is right or not is debatable. He's not the most sane individual himself, and has a very fatalistic viewpoint. I haven't played the game, so it's possible that Sam does go mad as a result of his bond with Lou, and then recover in the course of the game.

Comment: FWIW, there is bonus cutscene that exists in the game when the player subjects Sam & his BB to extreme stress; it has a relatively intolerable window to trigger and might require several attempts. First, Sam must be near death from exhaustion; Sam loses Stamina from doing pretty much anything excessively. This includes running, facing the elements, or fighting. Next, BB must be pushed to its limit and autotoxemic; Sam can cause upset to BB by falling from heights, wading through deep water for too long, being spotted by BTs, and many other ways. Then finally, Sam must enter recovery center.